# When adding a if-row Razor not finding the last bracket

Tags: c#, razor

My code looks like this:

```
<div class="accordion" id="accordion2">
@foreach (var news in newsList)
{
    string collapseID = "collapse" + @news.ID;
    string subscriptionName = news.SubscriptionID.ToString();

    bool findedSubscription = subscriptionList.Any(x => x.ID == news.SubscriptionID);

    if (findedSubscription)
    {

    }
}
</div>
```

When the `if(findedSubscription) { }` is added its not finding the last `}` for the `foreach`.

But do I not have the `if (findedSubscription) { }` rows its works fine and finding the last `}` for the foreach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because, for the if statements in Views in MVC, you need HTML elements to be displayed between them.

Try this and you'll see no errors:

```
if (findedSubscription)
{ 
    <span></span>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove '@' from below statement.

```
 string collapseID = "collapse" + @news.ID;
```

Correct statement is:

```
 string collapseID = "collapse" + news.ID;
```

Comment: thanks a "bug" i didnt see before i got the bracket problem fixed